# Menu items do nothing when clicked

Tags: android

So I am having a problem with my popup menu. It is working fine except that nothing happens when a menu item is clicked on. Here is the onClick event for the menuButton:

```
menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
                public void onClick(View v) {    
                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, menuButton);  
                    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());  

                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
                            if(item.getTitle() == "Stats") {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, StatsActivity.class);
                                activity.startActivity(intent);
                            } else if(item.getTitle() == "Reset") {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PrestiegeActivity.class);
                                activity.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            return true;  
                        }  
                    });  

                    popup.show(); 
                }  
            });
```

popup_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item  
        android:id="@+id/Stats"  
        android:title="Stats"/>  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/Reset"  
        android:title="Reset"/>  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/three"  
        android:title="Three"/>  
</menu>
```

I am not really sure where problem occurring is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not make the comparisons with the title strings. Instead compare the id.

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.Stats:
        doStuff();
        return true;
    case R.id.Reset:
        ...
        return true;
}
```

Also you cannot compare strings with the `==` operator. Instead you must use `theString.equals(theOtherString)`

Comment: Alright, thanks for adding that last part as well I was about to ask that next, ill mark as answer when I can. Appreciate the help.